# How to get all security groups that contain managedby?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As part of the access review, I need to provide a report of security groups. I would like to know how I can do to have the list of all the security groups whose managedby field has a value.

Also, i would like the managedby to show only the full name

Here what i have

```
get-ADGroup -filter {(Managedby -contains "*") -and (GroupCategory -eq "Security")} -Properties * | Select Name, SamAccountName, ManagedBy
```

Comment: What do you get from that query and how does it differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, the problem is `-contains` is a [PowerShell comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2) and is not supported by the [Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)).

When searching for an attribute **not null** *(usually)*:

- Using `-Filter`

```bash
"attributeName -like '*'"
```

- Using `-LDAPFilter`

```bash
"(attributeName=*)"
```

However for this case unfortunately I have no idea how to do this filter using `-Filter` (I personally dislike it), if you try:

```bash
Get-ADGroup -Filter "managedby -like '*'"
```

You would get the following error:

> Get-ADGroup : Operator(s): The following: ''Eq', 'Ne'' are the only operator(s) supported for searching on extended
> attribute: 'ManagedBy'.

So, using `-LDAPFilter`, this is how your code should look:

```bash
$params = @{
    LDAPFilter = '(&(ManagedBy=*)(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))'
    Properties = 'Name', 'SamAccountName', 'ManagedBy'
}
Get-ADGroup @params | Select-Object $params['Properties']
```

**`groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648`** in LDAP Syntax is for **Security Groups**, more details in [**Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)